# Metrics endpoint not working when deploying a Ballerina based micro service in Kubernetes

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, ballerina

I have a micro-service implemented in Ballerina. Whenever I deploy the service using following command, in my **local machine** `ballerina run --observe [name_of_the_file].bal`, I get `metrics endpoint` mapped to port `9797`. That is `curl localhost:9797/metrics` gives server metrics as a response.

Even when I deployed the above service in **Docker environment** I got the same results. But when I deployed it in **Kubernetes** (On GoogleCloudPlatform), I don't get the metrics mapped to the port `9797`.

`kubectl logs [pod_name]` gives the following output.

```
Initiating service(s) in 'ballerina-prime.balx'
[ballerina/http] started HTTP/WS endpoint 0.0.0.0:8688
```

Can someone help me get the metrics mapped to port `9797`?

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM ballerina/ballerina:0.991.0
COPY ballerina-prime.balx /home/ballerina
EXPOSE 8688 
EXPOSE 9797
CMD ballerina run --observe ballerina-prime.balx
```

**ballerina-prime.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ballerina-prime
  labels:
    app: ballerina-prime
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ballerina-prime
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ballerina-prime
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ballerina-prime
        image: anushiya/ballerina-prime:v3
        resources:
            limits:
                cpu: "100m"
            requests:
                cpu: "100m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8688
          name: echo-service
        - containerPort: 9797
          name: metrics
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a test, I ran the curl request within a Kubernetes node. First, find the podIP by using the following command:

```
kubectl get pods -l app=ballerina-prime -o yaml | grep podIP
```

app= [nameOfThePod].  You can use Cloud shell to get the  Pod IP.

-Next steps:

Since you're using GKE (Kubernetes) on Google Cloud Platform, navigate to Compute Engine and SSH to one of the GKE nodes. Once inside, run the curl request using the podIP IP 
    @gke-deploymentbuild-default-pool-f3c9c9aa-fkx5 ~ $ curl -i http://10.60.2.10:9797/metrics

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: text/plain
content-length: 1060
server: ballerina/0.991.0
date: Thu, 24 Oct 2019 18:19:29 GMT
```

-External:

Obviously, you wouldn't want to access this from a GKE Node, this is where Load Balancers come into play.

Navigate to GKE, and in workloads, select the ballerina workload. Once in the menu, select “Actions” and “Expose”. Here you can set the port number and select “load balancer” as the serviceType:

Menu>Kubernetes Engine>Workloads>”ballerina”>Actions>Expose>Service type: Load balancer.

Head over to services & ingress, and once the Load balancer is finish being created, you will see the endpoints exposed with the port number of your choice ( 9797 in this case.).  The IP with the /metrics endpoint should work.

See links: [1](https://github.com/DanyLan/GKE-EXPOSE-SERVICES/blob/master/ClusterIP.md) [3](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/ingress)

Comment: I tried this command from the node.`curl -i http://10.32.1.36:9797/metrics`. This is the output I got `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 10.32.1.18 port 8688: Connection refused`. Did you get that output in the answer using the artifacts I provided in the question?

Comment: I completely did everything from the beginning and now it is working. Did not know where mistake occurred.

Comment: I came up with a similar issue again and noticed that in Kubernetes, default image pull policy is`imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent`. Therfore even when I made changes to the docker image, and pushed to Dockerhub, Kubernetes used the previously cached image which prevented from not being updated. So to address this image pull policy can be changed to Always `imagePullPolicy: Always`

Answer (score 1):

Your container in pure docker environment will run the same in kubernetes. In fact, GKE runs on top of docker. If you exec into the pod, you should be able to reach the metrics on the same port:

> kubectl exec [pod_name] -- curl localhost:9797/metrics

Considering you are using the same image and your pod.spec had port 9797 exposed, I don't see why you should have avril issues, despite the loss showing a binding on port 8688

Comment: Even that's my confusion too. When it works perfectly in a Docker container, how come it fails to expose in Kubernetes platform?

Comment: After trying for so many times, it is working now. Didn't know where it went wrong.